# how to put a text under each fontawsome icon?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying since last 3 days to make simple thing, I looked at many topics and applied the same code but none of them worked.

> I have 3 icons
>   1-call
>   2-services
>   3-ticket
>   one more thing please , tell me if there is UI html and css builder inestead of coding i realy hate it from this week . the code below is not mine, its from youtube .

i want to lable every icon with a text and should be under the icon not beside .i am still frish in html and css .

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}


.middle{
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px #00000070;
  color: #1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.btn i{
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 26px;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}
.btn:hover i{
  transform: scale(1.3);
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.btn::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  background: #fbc531;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: -110%;
  top: 90%;
}
.btn:hover::before{
  animation: aaa 0.7s 1;
  top: -10%;
  left: -10%;
}
@keyframes aaa {
  0%{
    left: -110%;
    top: 90%;
  }50%{
    left: 10%;
    top: -30%;
  }100%{
    top: -10%;
    left: -10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">
      </head>



    <div class="middle">
      <a class="btn" href="">
         <i class="fas fa-headset">call</i>
           </a>
      <a class="btn" href="">
          <i class="fas fa-hands-helping">services</i>
          </a>
      <a class="btn" href="">
          <i class="fas fa-ticket-alt">ticket</i>
             </a>

      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can put it as a title like title="call" in the icon tag. It'll display when you will hover on that icon. 
or 
else 
you can do it like a button

```
  <button>Call <i class="fa fa-headset"></i> </button>
```

Comment: thnaks for reply, but i want it to display on btn mode not hover to show the user what it is before he put the pointer on it.

Comment: I dont understand it is already displaying correctly under your icon tag.

Comment: no Man,  as you see all texts beside the icans(from right side) , for example : i want the text " call" be at the bottom of the headphone icon. hop u got it now

Comment: there is a styling attribute called content in the font awesome css for icon through which the icon gets displayed but we cant add text within the same icon. maybe it can be adjusted by css but not as an attribute value within the tag

Comment: maybe if the title attribute styling can be done as default that is without on hover then this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a span after the icon.

```
<span>Call</span>
```

Comment: @parono add css to fas as .fas{ display: block; width:100%;} and call after closing of i tag

Comment: guys thank you for your effort , but nothing work i have done every possible suggestion but Non of them work , u may try the code yourself if u dont belev me . i dont know what is wrong there , why me!!